# Angularjs: dir-pagination-controls doesn't show the next page, even after the page button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

I've been trying to incorporate `dir-pagination-controls`, but can't work display the page based on the chosen page.

```
<div ng-controller="TableController as tc">
    <table>
        <tbody dir-paginate="order in tc.orders | itemsPerPage: 10" total-items="tc.totalOrders" current-page="currentPage">
            <tr ng-click="tc.showOrderDetail(order.id)">
                <td ng-bind="order.id"></td>
                <!-- Simliar lines are here -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <dir-pagination-controls 
       boundary-links="true" 
       on-page-change="tc.pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" 
       template-url="dirPagination.tpl.html">
    </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

This `table` shows what I expect. However, the resulting pagination controller doesn't show the next page when I press any of its buttons.

Here is a relevant part of the script.

```
angular.module('adminAngular', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs.main','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination'])
.controller('TableController', function($http){

    var instance = this;

    this.orders = [];
    $http({
        //works fine
    }).then(function (response) {
        instance.orders = response.data;
        instance.totalOrders = instance.orders.length;
        //The "instance.orders" gets the expected data, and used for in dir-paginate="order in tc.orders
    });

    this.pageChangeHandler = function(num) {
        console.log('going to page ' + num);
    };

    this.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
        getResultsPage(newPage);
    };
```

**UPDATE** The `pageChangeHandler` shows which button was pressed, but the page doesn't change. (Everything else is fine.)

This code is based on [the official document and its demo](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination),but I can't find what is actually wrong.

I'd appreciate if you give any advice.

Comment: Shouldn't the line on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)"  be on-page-change="tc.pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" ?

Comment: You are right!! I'll fix this post...

Comment: Are you invoking the method this.pageChanged() anywhere? I guess you might have to invoke it from pageChangedHandler() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to remove `total-items` from your `dir-paginate` directive.
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gp03nehmYvBKDbtHsQg0?p=preview) with the simple example.

The `total-items` attribute is used when you do async calls to get **each** page items.
So, first async call you get items for first page, and when you change the page you are supposed to get from the server the items for the corresponding page.
The `total-items` tell the pagination directive how many pages you have in total, so it knows how to build the element.

If you want an async call for each page, you use `total-items` and you implement `pageChanged` where you do another async call.

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
   // get orders for newPage number
   $http.get(...).then(function(response) {
       // orders for newPage number fill the same 'orders' array
       this.orders = response.data
   });
}
```